# Question About Group Theory Notation

Tags: group-theory, notation

I am having trouble understanding what "Universal Cover of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$" mean exactly.

Thanks

Comment: Some context would be nice. Have you encountered this in the context of geometric group theory? Were Cayley graphs introduced there?

Answer (score 0):

A topological space X has a universal cover if and only if it is connected, locally path connected, and semi-locally simply connected. You may now relate this concept with $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$